# (Telegram bot) JSON post request doesn't work

Tags: java, json, telegram-bot

I'm trying to show a custom keyboard to the receiver of the message I'm sending.

However, I don't know exactly why but the following code doesn't work well when I try to append `reply_markup` parameter in json String.

I'm guessing it is because I put `reply_markup` array in a wrong way but can't find out the way to fix.

```
String query = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendmessage";
String json = "{\"chat_id\":188784029,\"text\":\"123123\",\"reply_markup\":{\"keyboard\":[['1','2'],['3','4']], \"one_time_keyboard\":true}}";

URL url = new URL(query);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.close();

// read the response
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
String result = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");


in.close();
conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: You can try this api https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api instead of implementing everything by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid JSON, as you should use `"` instead of `'`.

```
['1','2'],['3','4']
```

Should be replaced by:

```
["1","2"],["3","4"]
```